# Java EE server calling itself

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

So I might be going about this the wrong way, but I would like some way of knowing what port my API is running on. And I don't really want it be specific to any application server(but if I must then it is ok).

So I created a function that calls a specific path for all used ports.

```
private static Optional<Integer> findPort(String serviceName) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    client.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    client.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 10);
    try {
        //Even this breaks
        Response res = client.target("http://127.0.0.1:8080/movies/api/discover/self").request().get();
        for (int s = 0; s <= 1; s++)
            for (int i = 9999; i > 0; i--) {
                try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(i)) {
                    continue;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                Response response = null;
                try {
                    String target = String.format("%s127.0.0.1:%d", (s == 0 ? "https://" : "http://"), i);
                    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(target)
                                                .path(String.format("/%s/", serviceName))
                                                .path("/api/discover/self");
                    target = webTarget.getUri().toString();
                    response = webTarget.request().get();
                    int responseStatus = response.getStatus();
                    String data = response.readEntity(String.class);

                    if (responseStatus == 200 && data.equals(id))
                        return Optional.of(i);
                } catch (ProcessingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (response != null) response.close();
                }
            }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

But for some reason I always get a read timeout exception and I cannot figure out why that is.

```
private static String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

@GET
@Path("/self")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response selfDiscover() {
    return Response.ok(id).build();
}
```

That is the enpoint I am calling.
And if it of any use I am running this on a tomcat 8 server.

So, the question is, why am I not getting a response from my own server(if I call the enpoint it works)

Comment: "So I created a function that calls a specific path for all used ports.". Ah, the bogosort of port discovery. This isn't a very smart move, why don't you just read it from a configuration file for example.

Comment: yes, that is an option and probably the "smart" move. but I wanted it to be smart and find itself

Comment: But it's not smart, which is why I compared it to [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort). A better idea would be to use JMX for example, and ask the server itself for details. Your approach also assumes naively that there is a single port, and won't work if you have a reverse proxy with port forwarding. I'm not sure why you think this is a good idea, or even why you think you need this.

Comment: The problem with that(I might be wrong) is that if I were to use JMX, I still need to specify what port that is, right?
And my plan with this is to avoid configuration as much as possible. I want it to just run anywere without any config. You are right that it is a naive approach as it would break if there is a reverse proxy....

Comment: Why do you need to know the port? I also don't see why you'd need to know any ports when using JMX. I think you're trying to be too clever for your own good.